# How to develop and test spark specific aws glue code in my local without using docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-glue

I have a spark code that runs on a glue job and  the code needs to tested locally and generate sonar coverage reports for the unit tests. The issue is that I can not import glue specific libraries in my local .I installed awsglue-local 1.0.2 and fake-awsglue python libaries and none of them seem to work. At an organization level , I have restrictions using docker as stated here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-docker-image . The documentation here :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-using-etl-library is not for windows.
code here:

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.transforms import DropNullFields
from awsglue.transforms import ApplyMapping
from awsglue.transforms import SelectFields
from awsglue.transforms import ResolveChoice
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

Errors here:

```
    from dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dynamicframe'
awsglue.utils.GlueArgumentError: the following arguments are required: --JOB_NAME
```

How do we solve this?